# Not able to use promise successfully

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Issue in resolving promises in angular. I want promise.then method to execute after the execution of getUsersRegister(-). But, the method present inside the promise.then() is executing first before the former method.
Is that the way I wrote the promise concept is right or need to modify something else.

```
   function getMysers(){
        var promise = getUsersRegister(teamId);
    promise.then(friendsService.myFriends.query({},function(data){ 
    var users = data;
        }));
   }

   function getUsersRegister(teamId){
       var q = $q.defer(); 

       teamService.fetchData(function(data){
            q.resolve(data);
         var results = data;
        });
        return q.promise;
    }
```

Comment: Can you try to return q.promise in fetchData function? I think you need to add return teamService.fetchData(..) too

Comment: One thing I'm noticing is that you could wrap the `then` callback in a function